# Kotlin String replace including delimiter

Tags: kotlin

I have a common pattern where I want to operate on a string like `abckey123` where I want to clear the string before `key` but also remove the `key`.

Is there a commonly accepted way to do this? Or even better a way to make this a single method call on all string objects?

Ideas:

```
item.replaceBefore("key", "").replace("key", "")
```

```
item.split("key").last()
```

Comment: Does the pattern repeat? If your source is "abckey123abckey123", what do you expect? Removing the first  `key`, "123abckey123", or all `key` "123'

Comment: it really depends what you want to accomplish... if there is a pattern, then a convenient approach is to use regex with groups and extract those groups instead... e.g. `"""(.*?)?key(\d+)""".toRegex().findAll(yourInputString).map { it.destructured }.forEach { (firstPart, secondPart) -> println("$firstPart -> $secondPart") }`... In this example the regex extracts everything before the last `key` into group 1 and every digit after `key` to group 2. So with an input of `somekey123` it would print `some -> 123` and with `somekeykey123` it would print `somekey -> 123`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get all text after the "key" substring, you can use `substringAfter` function:

```
val result = item.substringAfter("key")
```

The second parameter of this function allows to specify what to return if the delimiter is not found. By default it returns the entire string, but you can pass an empty string for example:

```
val result = item.substringAfter("key", "")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. With `substringAfterLast` and the `before` methods as well, this is great.

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = "abckey123".replace(".*key".toRegex(), {""})
println(result)
```

it gives `123`